# Cannot run sudo twice

Tags: sudo, pam, bacula

I have the following statement in bacula:

```
RunBeforeJob = "sudo /bin/mountpoint /backup/external || sudo /bin/mount /dev/mapper/bacula"
```

But it fails:

```
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [bacula]
sudo: pam_succeed_if(sudo:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "bacula"
sudo:  bacula : command not allowed ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mountpoint /backup/external || sudo /bin/mount /dev/mapper/bacula
```

I've found that bacula user can run one command in "RunBeforeJob" but cannot two commands. I don't understand why and how to fix it. I wonder that if I remove the pam restriction of "uid >=1000" it would work, but I'd like to find a better solution.

Note: I've disable requiretty in sudoers.

Comment: The problem is that `sudo` is trying to run `/bin/mountpoint /backup/external || sudo /bin/mount /dev/mapper/bacula` as a single command, where presumably it is allowed to run `sudo /bin/mountpoint /backup/external` or `sudo /bin/mount /dev/mapper/bacula`. Maybe bacula doesn't support shell syntax in `RunBeforeJob`. Putting your commands in a script and use that as `RunBeforeJob` may work.

Comment: @muru Your solution worked. You may want to post it as an answer :)